# How do two structures with same name and with different Template arguments work

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Why does only first implementation work and not the other implementations specified below,
Can someone explain the way this template structure work and why others do not.

*Template structures that work*

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

*Template structures that do not work*

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same<T, U>
{
   static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
  static const bool value = true;
};
```

*One more  that does not work*

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same<T,U>
{
   static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

And the Main Function

```
template <class A, class B>
bool IsSameClass() {
  return is_same<A, B>::value;
}
int main()
{
  bool ret =    IsSameClass<P,C>();
}
```

Comment: Look at template **specialization**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You always start with a template definition:

```
template <class T, class U>
class is_same { ... };
```

Or, as Jarod42 reminded me, with a declaration:

```
template <class T, class U> class is_same;
```

Once there's a template, you can define a **partial specialization** by refining one or more of the template arguments, as in your example:

```
template <class T>
class is_same<T, T> { ...};
```

The specialization still takes two arguments, just like the original template, but they're the same type, so there's only one type name in the `template <...>` part of the definition.

In use, `is_same<int, double>` would match the template definition; `is_same<int, int>` would match the partial specialization.

You can also specify a full specialization. Not that you'd want to here, but following on with this example:

```
template <>
class is_same<void, void> { ... };
```

This would match, obviously, `is_same<void, void>`.

The reason that the other two attempts don't work is that neither of them has a template **definition**, only things that look like specializations. Without a definition there's nothing to specialize.

Note that this is a bit of an oversimplification. It's intended to address "why don't these things work", not "how can I specialize a template".

Comment: We can start only with the **declaration**.

Comment: @pete Becker Thanks a ton , can you also explain how to specialise a template .

Answer (score 1):

The syntax

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same<T, U>
{
   static const bool value = false;
};
```

is used to create a specialization of a class template. In order to do that, you have to first declare the template or create its generic definition first.

```
template <typename T, typename U> struct is_same;
```

or

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = false;
};
```

Even if you did that,

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same<T, U>
{
   static const bool value = false;
};
```

is not a valid specialization since there is no way to decide which template to use when instantiated with `is_same<int, float>`.

Templates cannot be overloaded by using:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same
{
   static const bool value = true;
};
```

The language simply does not allow that.